# Dynamic array and functionalize malloc

Tags: c, arrays

I try to malloc an array functionally, and this function also can check whether the memory is enough or not.

The first code block can't work.
When it executes " `*pi = 5` ", the compiler shows this error message " `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0) "` .

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void malloc_and_check(int *var)
 {
     if(!(var = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))))
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient Memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     } 
 }

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
 {
    int *pi;
    malloc_and_check(pi);
    *pi = 5;
    printf("%d", *pi);
    free(pi);
 }
```

However, the codes as below can work normally.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        int *pi;

        if(!(pi = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient Memory\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        *pi = 5;
        printf("%d", *pi);
        free(pi);
    }
```

What are the difference between them? Thanks!

Comment: You must pass `void malloc_and_check(int **var)` and call it with `malloc_and_check(&pi);` Also **do not** cast the return of `malloc`

Comment: Use `perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` on `malloc` failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer var is allocated memory dynamically but it is local to the function malloc_and_check. The pointer pi in the function main will not get to know the address of the memory allocated to var. It is a bad access and may also result in crash sometimes.

try the code below to get the expected results :

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void malloc_and_check(int **var)
 {
     int *var1;
     if(!(var1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))))
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient Memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     } 
     else 
        *var = var1;
 }

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
 {
    int *pi;
    malloc_and_check(&pi);
    *pi = 5;
    printf("%d", *pi);
    free(pi);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass the `int * var` into `malloc_and_check` you are updating a local copy of the pointer so the original is unchanged. You can fix this in two ways:
(a) return the pointer from `malloc_and_check`

```
int * malloc_and_check()
{
    int * var = 0;
    if(!(var = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient Memory\n");
        return 0;
    } 
    return var;
}
```

Then you would call it as

```
pi = malloc_and_check();
```

(b) pass in a pointer to the pointer

```
void malloc_and_check(int ** var)
{
    if(!( *var = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient Memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
}
```

Then you would pass it in as

```
 malloc_and_check(&pi);
```

Comment: Yes, another way to explain it is that when anything is passed as a function parameter, the function receives a ***copy*** (with its very own, and very different address). In the case of an allocated pointer, it makes no difference, because the ***value*** of the pointer still points to the original block of memory. However, with an unallocated pointer, the address returned by `malloc` is assigned to the copy of the pointer and there is no correlation to the original pointer address back in `main`. (which also results in a memory leak)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass the pointer by value (pass by value). You need to pass a double pointer to the function  `malloc_and_check`. Due to this the value assigned to the pointer is not reflecting back in the caller.

Please modify your code as below:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void malloc_and_check(int **var)
 {
     if(!(*var = malloc(sizeof(int))))
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient Memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     } 
 }

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
 {
    int *pi;
    malloc_and_check(&pi);
    *pi = 5;
    printf("%d", *pi);
    free(pi);
 }
```

Comment: I got you by 3 seconds `:)` Get rid of the cast for `malloc`

Comment: @David, : )). Done!!

Comment: Perfect. I'd give you the SO sight, but I'm changing laptops and have lost my 2nd quick reference brain (Basket Notepads -- kde3)

Answer (score 0):

The change you make to `var` in the function is lost when the function returns. Either you need to pass `var` as a double pointer or you need to return a pointer from the function.

Example where the function returns a pointer:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int* malloc_and_check()
 {
     int *var;
     if(!(var = malloc(sizeof(int))))
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient Memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     } 
     return var;
 }

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
 {
    int *pi;
    pi = malloc_and_check();
    *pi = 5;
    printf("%d", *pi);
    free(pi);
 }
```

Comment: Assigning the return is another option, but technically, that's the answer to a slightly different question. (but I won't split hairs)